# Upgrading Intel Matrix Storage Manager to Intel Rapid Storage Technology, windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, software-raid

I would like to upgrade the Intel Matrix Storage Manager software on a windows 2003 std box to the latest version of Intel Rapid Storage Technology which my mobo (ASUS P6X58D-E) supports.

Can someone explain the process? I've done it one time before but the details are rather distant. Is it possible to do it from inside of windows (after a full backup)? I would really like to have as detailed an explanation as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Intel page](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-020930.htm):

To upgrade to Intel® Rapid Storage Technology from Intel® Matrix Storage Manager, follow these steps:

1. Download the latest version of Intel Rapid Storage Technology from
   Download Center.
2. Double-click the file to install the software.
3. Restart the computer.

An uninstall of the older software is not required.

Comment: Confirmed, I have done the upgrade on my machine and it was as straightforward as that. Sounds like meridian is concerned about this affecting the configuration of existing arrays - rest assured that the upgrade doesn't affect the config, but do take a backup if you don't have one.